# Select distinct for one column and many in another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have:

```
Name PhoneNo
JOHN 555555
JOHN 555554
MIKE 111111
MIKE 122222
```

I want to display output like:

```
Name PhoneNo
JOHN 555555
     555554
MIKE 111111
     111112
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach is using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #Phones (
    Name varchar(10),
    PhoneNo varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Phones 
    (Name, PhoneNo)
VALUES  
    ('JOHN', '555555'),
    ('JOHN', '555554'),
    ('JOHN', '555553'),
    ('MIKE', '111111'),
    ('MIKE', '122222')

-- Statement
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) = 1 THEN Name
        ELSE ''
    END AS Name,
    PhoneNo
FROM #Phones
```

Output:

```
Name    PhoneNo
JOHN    555555
        555554
        555553
MIKE    111111
        122222
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to **display** output like

As a general rule display matters should not be handled in the database. The DB calls should return the data and aggregates & other amalgamations/calculations based upon it, and your application's UI layer should decide what to display from that.

It is possible though, for instance using the [`LAG()` window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) to track changes in the value:

```
SELECT LastName = CASE WHEN LastName = LAG(LastName) OVER (ORDER BY LastName, FirstName) THEN NULL ELSE LastName END
     , FirstName
FROM   Person
ORDER BY Person.LastName, Person.FirstName
```

It is strongly not recommended that you tightly connect the data layer and presentation layer of your application in such a manner though.